# UPDATE statement not working in ibm db2 but it working in phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, db2, data-science, ibm-cloud

I am new to ibm db2 and phpmyadmin. In this code I was trying to update a specific column value twice. This code was working well in phpmyadmin but not work in db2. Here is my code (ibm db2):

```
    CREATE TABLE PETSALE (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PET CHAR(20),
    SALEPRICE DECIMAL(6,2),
    PROFIT DECIMAL(6,2),
    SALEDATE DATE
    );
    
    INSERT INTO PETSALE VALUES
    (1,'Cat',450.09,100.47,'2018-05-29'),
    (2,'Dog',666.66,150.76,'2018-06-01'),
    (3,'Parrot',50.00,8.9,'2018-06-04'),
    (4,'Hamster',60.60,12,'2018-06-11'),
    (5,'Goldfish',48.48,3.5,'2018-06-14');
    
        ALTER TABLE PETSALE
        ADD COLUMN QUANTITY INTEGER;
        
        SELECT * FROM PETSALE;
    
        UPDATE PETSALE SET QUANTITY = 9 WHERE ID = 1;
        UPDATE PETSALE SET QUANTITY = 3 WHERE ID = 2;
        UPDATE PETSALE SET QUANTITY = 2 WHERE ID = 3;
        UPDATE PETSALE SET QUANTITY = 6 WHERE ID = 4;
        UPDATE PETSALE SET QUANTITY = 24 WHERE ID = 5;
        
        SELECT * FROM PETSALE;
```

then I open the PETSALE table to update last value of QUANTITY again.

```
UPDATE "NDH77177"."PETSALE"
  SET "QUANTITY" = 22 
WHERE "ID" = 5;
```

but it's not working on ibm db2. It's showing an error message-

```
Operation not allowed for reason code "7" on table "NDH77177.PETSALE".. SQLCODE=-668, SQLSTATE=57007, DRIVER=4.31.10
```

Here is the image also:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWXuo.png)

how to fix this issue :(

Comment: Does this tool show the error message from the last statement? [This](https://dbfiddle.uk/wJpBW1Vq) works good enough...

Comment: The description of [SQL0668N](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=messages-sql0500-sql0749) with suggestion on how to resolve it. Your example can't be used to reproduce the problem. The table is placed into such a state because you issued one of the so called `REORG-recommended` statements against it listed at the [ALTER TABLE statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-alter-table) link. The full list of such statements is in the `Notes` section there. None of these statements are visible in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are on LUW. The error means that you probably altered the table to many times, your table is in REORG PENDING STATE. Db2 allows you to do a certain amount of "destructive" operations on a table before you have to REORG it. You can investigate if other tables are in the same situation with:

```
SELECT tabschema, tabname
FROM SYSIBMADM.ADMINTABINFO 
WHERE NUM_REORG_REC_ALTERS > 2
```

To fix the problem you [REORG](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-reorg-table) the table:

```
REORG TABLE NDH77177.PETSALE
```

or if you only have access to the database via an sql-client, you can run the procedure [ADMIN_CMD](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=procedure-admin-cmd-run-administrative-commands):

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('REORG TABLE NDH77177.PETSALE')
```